# Lm311 as open loop controller for boost converter

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck-boost, positive-feedback

[image]

Recently I’ve wanted to make a boost converter. To keep the output voltage stable when a load is connected there need to be a feedback from the output. The circuit above claim that it will keep the frequency solid and vary the duty cycle according to the voltage reference from the output. The question is I wanted to replace the LM393 with LM311, so according to the schematic I would like to hear opinions and solution about it. Perhaps any other solution?
Thank you

Comment: If closing a negative feedback loop were only that simple. Read up on "frequency compensation".

Comment: I hope you're only building this / looking at this for "educational purposes" because a 555 timer based boost converter usually doesn't have good performance. Consider using a boost converter IC or module if you want a "proper" boost converter which can drive a load which takes some current.

Comment: They do make better PWM IC's. https://www.mouser.com/Analog-Devices-Inc/Switching-Controllers/LTC6992-1-Series/_/N-1yyh4l4Z41fauZ1y994dp

Comment: Ya im going to build this for testing and educational purposes.but a proper boost converter i would use tl494 or other pwm ics that is suitable for this type of purposes

Comment: I just want to know how this circuit  really works

Comment: @Mr.Infinite The circuit can't regulate voltage as-is, you need an additional ingredient. The output from the boost converter needs to be compared to some fixed reference voltage and the resulting error signal needs to be fed back to the comparator. But again, it's not going to be stable.

Comment: The circuitry shown IS a pulse-width modulator, but it only senses the R5 potentiometer setting, not a power source output voltage.   It does not supply power.